# MSTestV2 assemblies in GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mstest, .net-4.6.1

Using VS2017 with mstest.testadapter 2.1.1 and mstest.testframework 2.1.1 (nugets)

When opening 'Developer command prompt", running command "vstest.console.exe my_test.dll", all tests are executed as expected. The folder that contains "my_test.dll" also contains the following assemblies/xml files;

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.interface.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.xml
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.xml

We added all five assemblies to GAC, executed same command again and got an error message:
"Failed to discover test from assembly c:\temp\bin\my_test.dll Reason: could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, publicKeyToken=b03f3..." or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
No test is available in c:\temp\bin\my_test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are approperiate and try again."*

1. Does vstest.console.exe support mstest assemblies being located in GAC?
2. Does vstest.console.exe require any other parameters to use the GAC from commandline? Maybe the "TestAdapterPath" could be used but not sure what path to use.
3. It is also interesting that error message references an assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resource" that was not needed in the original successful example.

Appreciate any input on the matter.

Comment: ... *why* would you add these assemblies to the GAC? They *definitely* don't belong there, aren't meant to be there, can't be conveniently serviced from there and it's overall just such a bad idea that I'm having a hard time imagining the scenario where this is desirable or useful. Having the deployed tests include the framework and adapter assemblies as part of the build is a feature, not a bug. For automated test setups on a build server, use NuGet (possibly in combination with your own NuGet host if you don't want to download anything).

Comment: Appreciate your response. We have a plugin and test-plugin assembly that are used by a commercial software framework. Both plugin and test-plugin are located outside AppDomain.BaseDirectory of framework application and are added to GAC (requirement of framework). The test-plugin requires mstest assmblies to execute and need to find them. In this context we found that placing the mstest assemblies in commercial FW application dir will work or in GAC. Ideally we do not want to copy files into commercial FW folders and therefore wanted to investigate using GAC. Hope this make sense.

Comment: If it has a hard dependency on MSTest itself you must always build every test project with *exactly* the version it requires -- no NuGet test frameworks for you. That would be pretty bad. If it only requires that your assembly to invoke the tests is in the GAC, I'd write a wrapper assembly that can be configured to take the path of the test directory/name of the plugin and takes care of running the tests wherever they may be. This can then be hard-linked to whatever interface your framework requires, while keeping the actual tests free from those dependencies once and for all.